# program to determine palindrome is only executing the else condition

Tags: java, palindrome

I am trying to get the palindrome of a string  and below is my code. The problem is, it is only executing the else condition

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "aba";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(name);

        sb = sb.reverse();
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(name);
        if (sb.equals(name)) {
            System.out.println(name + " is palindrome");
        } else 
           System.out.println(name + " isn't palindrome");
     }
}
```

Only the `else` condition is executed.

Comment: Try to compare two `String`s, not a `StringBuilder` and a `String`, so do `if (sb.toString().equals(name))`, maybe...

Comment: use `sb.toString().equals(name)` as condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sb.toString()`

```
if(sb.toString().equals(name)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to compare instance of a StringBuilder with a String. Those are two separate classes. You should first convert the builder to a string, then compare.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name = "aba";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(name);
        sb = sb.reverse();
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(name);
        if (sb.toString().equals(name))
        {
            System.out.println(name + " is palindrome");
        } else System.out.println(name + " isn't palindrome");
    }
```